# Create a dynamic sized mask tensor with indices as filter

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to create a mask tensor to a image tensor with 4 dimension (batch,h,w,channel), the size of the batch might vary. The mask is basically a rectangle region on the image with given x and y locations.
The x and y are also tensors from upper layers.
in numpy it would be like :

```
imagetensor.shape =(none,h,w,c)
mask[:]=0
mask[:,y1:y2,x1:x2,:]=1
```

I tried to set the mask as variables, but it requires the shape of the input image. and I can't find a method to set the mask with x and y value. Is there an efficient method to do these?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.pad()`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x1, x2, y1, y2 = 2, 3, 4, 5
h, w = 6, 7
t = tf.ones((x2-x1, y2-y1), tf.int32)
paddings = tf.constant([[x1, h-x2], [y1, w-y2]])
mask = tf.pad(t, paddings, "CONSTANT")
mask = tf.expand_dims(mask, 0)
batch_size = 8
output = tf.repeat(mask, [batch_size], axis=0)
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, how do I implement this with unknown batch size as the first channel?